# Как импорт видео в группу вк php?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, видео

Подскажите как реализовать загрузку видео в вк с youtube

Допустим есть список url и вcя инфа о видео в формате json

Каким запросом и т.д. через ВК API загрузить видео в видеозаписи группы (а если можно то и в альбом)

С ВК АПИ не работал так что нужен либо пример либо подробное объяснение, буду благодарен очень!

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Все, разобрался, кому нужно:

- Сначала получаем токен.
- Далее подключаем библиотеку ВК.
- После чего используем ссылку в виде:

  https://api.vk.com/method/video.save?is_private=0&wallpost=0&group_id=&link=https://www.youtube.com/&access_token=
- После чего получаем `upload_url` и выполняем его!